# Как добавить поддержку Jade в Kohana?

Tags: jade, kohana-3, kohana

Кто-нибудь пробовал добавлять поддержку Jade в Kohana (3.3)?
Нашел репозиторий с модулем, https://github.com/pocesar/jade-kohana, но он не работает (видимо, для старой версии).
Если у кого-нибудь получилось, поделитесь опытом.

UPD

Ошибка

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Method Kohana_JadeView::__toString() must not throw an exception
SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Response.php [ 0 ]
1 <?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');
2 /**
3  * Response wrapper. Created as the result of any [Request] execution
4  * or utility method (i.e. Redirect). Implements standard HTTP
5  * response format.
{PHP internal call} » Kohana_Core::shutdown_handler()
```

Код контроллера

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Test extends Controller {
    function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body(JadeView::factory('jtemplate'));
    }
}
```

Код шаблона

```
!!!
html
  head
    title Hello Jade World
  body
    h1=hello
```

Comment: Как именно он не работает? Подсказать, что-то можно было бы, но ставить Kohana неохота.

Comment: ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Method Kohana_JadeView::__toString() must not throw an exception